# Saving to xml file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save to an xml file using a datagridview. But its giving an error. Can anyone help me. Please find my code below.

i am getting this error :"Exception:Access to the path 'C:\settings.xml' is denied."

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Try
            'Write dataset to XML file
            DS.WriteXml(txtXMLFilePath)
            MessageBox.Show("XML data saved successfully to " + txtXMLFilePath)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: 1. What is the error? 2. What is `DS` and how is it populated? 3. What is your question?

Comment: DS is dataset.error is :Exception:Access to the path 'C:\settings.xml' is denied

Comment: So, this has **nothing** to do with XML at this point. It is about permissions.

Comment: can you guide me to over come this error

Comment: I mean i need to save data to my xml file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the .Net worker process has write access to that directory. You may be using the Administrator account, but the .Net worker process (typically 'IIS_IUSRS') is what is trying to write to the directory.

This is to ensure that your application is not an Administrator, as running an application pool under an account that has high-level user rights is a serious security risk.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the account under which the application is executing does not have permissions to write to the file location specified.

You need to either use an account that does have these permissions or add the needed permissions to the account being used.

Comment: I am using the administrator account .

Comment: @IsseY - Then it doesn't have permissions to write to that location or file. Check the folder permissions.